# Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for - org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Permanent Redirect (308)

Tags: maven, grails

I'm trying to run a legacy system (using *Grails 2.3.7* and *JDK 7*) for development locally which until now has worked as usual.

I was getting another error that I solved deleting the folders `.m2` and `.grails` in my home. After that, it seems maven isn't able to download the dependencies:

```scala
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:tomcat:zip:7.0.52.1
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.0.2

Caused by: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Permanent Redirect (308)
```

<sub>Full log [here](https://pastebin.com/gtDchXFa).</sub>

Probably I'm missing something but the plugin can be reached from [repo.grails.org repository](https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/plugins/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/).

**How do I get around this problem?.**

<sub>For the time being, I partially solved the error by copying my coworkers `.m2` and `.grails` folder but when I change some dependency in the `BuildConfid.groovy` this error shows up again.</sub>

**BuildConfig.groovy (repositories)**:

```java
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    // mavenCentral()
    // mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    // mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    mavenRepo "http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2"
    mavenRepo "http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Workaround

Besides the obvious solution of upgrading Grails, to simply solve this problem it's possible to **use Java 8 to download the dependencies and Java 7 to run the application.**

##### 1. Replace all Grails and Maven Central http repositories with its https equivalents (including `grailsCentral()` and `grailsPlugins()`):

```scala
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenRepo "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
    mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
    mavenRepo "https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/artifactory/third-party-ce-artifacts"
```

Don't forget to also remove the line with `inherits true`.

##### 2. Refresh (download) the dependencies using Java 8:

<sub>If you want to do this only on Intellij, you can change SDK version at <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> > <kbd>Project</kbd> > <kbd>SDK</kbd>. Beware that Intellij may build Grails automatically so it might be necessary to restart the IDE.</sub>

The following are the commands to refresh the project's dependencies using Grails command `refresh-dependencies` directly through Java in Linux or Windows.

Linux:

```bash
# Change java command to Java 8 full path if needed
G_HOME="</path/to/grails_home>" java -Dgrails.home="$G_HOME"  \
    -Dgroovy.starter.conf="$G_HOME/conf/groovy-starter.conf" \
    -classpath "$G_HOME/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.1.9.jar:$G_HOME/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.3.4.jar" \
    org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter \
    --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner \
    --conf "$G_HOME/conf/groovy-starter.conf" \
    "refresh-dependencies"
```

Windows CMD (Not tested):

```bash
set G_HOME=</path/to/grails_home>

# Change java command to Java 8 executable full path if needed:    
java -Dgrails.home=%G_HOME% ^
    -Dgroovy.starter.conf=%G_HOME%/conf/groovy-starter.conf ^
    -classpath %G_HOME%/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.1.9.jar:%G_HOME%/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.3.4.jar ^
    org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter ^
    --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner ^
    --conf %G_HOME%/conf/groovy-starter.conf ^
    refresh-dependencies
```

#### 3. After downloading the dependencies (step 2), run using Java 7

Don't forget to clean the project (delete the `target` folder) and change Java version back to 7.

---

The problem is http://repo.grails.org is redirecting to https and no longer accepting http connections.

I tried using Java 7 and Maven with Grails https repository enabling TLS version 1.2 support and adding Java Cryptography Extension (JCE). Eventually got stuck in a TLS handshake problem which I was short in time to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Your repositories need to use https now.  Try these examples below:

```
repositories {
    mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
    mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
```

Also I had to use Java 8 to get them to download.  Since 2.3.7 does not support Java 8 you could upgrade grails to 2.4.x or 2.5.x which does support Java 8.  Or you could also try using TLS 1.2 when using Java 7 trying enabling TLS 1.2 in Java 7:

java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2